# Simplify a if - if ladder - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I need to simplify these lines of code to less than 4 if's. Not sure how i can achieve that:

```
    for response in response_json:
        for appliance in response['versanms.ApplianceStatusResult']['appliances']:
            temp_item = OrderedDict()
            if 'name' in appliance:
                temp_item['name'] = appliance['name']
            if 'type' in appliance:
                temp_item['type'] = appliance['type']
            if 'ping-status' in appliance:
                temp_item['ping-status'] = appliance['ping-status']
            if 'sync-status' in appliance:
                temp_item['sync-status'] = appliance['sync-status']
            if 'services-status' in appliance:
                temp_item['services-status'] = appliance['services-status']
            if 'orgs' in appliance:
                temp_item['orgs'] = appliance['orgs']
            if 'ownerOrg' in appliance:
                temp_item['ownerOrg'] = appliance['ownerOrg']
            if 'softwareVersion' in appliance:
                temp_item['softwareVersion'] = appliance['softwareVersion']
            if 'ipAddress' in appliance:
                temp_item['ipAddress'] = appliance['ipAddress']
            if appliance is not None:
                appliance_list.insert(0, temp_item)
return {'appliance': appliance_list}
```

Need to remove the if's because our code validation tool doesn't like more than 4 if's in one method :(

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace all of this:

```
if 'name' in appliance:
    temp_item['name'] = appliance['name']
if 'type' in appliance:
    temp_item['type'] = appliance['type']
if 'ping-status' in appliance:
    temp_item['ping-status'] = appliance['ping-status']
if 'sync-status' in appliance:
    temp_item['sync-status'] = appliance['sync-status']
if 'services-status' in appliance:
    temp_item['services-status'] = appliance['services-status']
if 'orgs' in appliance:
    temp_item['orgs'] = appliance['orgs']
if 'ownerOrg' in appliance:
    temp_item['ownerOrg'] = appliance['ownerOrg']
if 'softwareVersion' in appliance:
    temp_item['softwareVersion'] = appliance['softwareVersion']
if 'ipAddress' in appliance:
    temp_item['ipAddress'] = appliance['ipAddress']
```

with a loop:

```
for x in ['name', 'type', 'ping-status', 'sync-status',
          'services-status', 'orgs', 'ownerOrg',
          'softwareVersion', 'ipAddress']:
    if x in appliance:
        temp_item[x] = appliance[x]
```

Comment: To take it one step further: `for x in {'name',...} & set(appliance.keys()): temp_item[x] = appliance[x]`.

Comment: @Chris Martin thanks for the solution. 
Your solution worked perfectly!!!
but used the "a step further" solution by Dyz since it was a bit neater in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use all of the values from appliance rather than a select few then a for .. in appliance.keys() will work.

```
appliance = { 'name':'this is the name', 'type': 'this is the type', 'ping-status': 'this is the ping status' }
temp_item = OrderedDict()

for field_name in appliance.keys():
    temp_item[field_name] = appliance[field_name]

print temp_item
```

output
{'ping-status': 'this is the ping status', 'type': 'this is the type', 'name': 'this is the name'}