# Trying to simplify yet another if-else ladder in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I tried implementing the same logic as "[Simplify a if - if ladder - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421449/simplify-a-if-if-ladder-python)" which i had requested earlier to simplify a if else ladder. But for the life of me, i am not able to simplify this one.

```
for each_component in component_objects:
    if each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'pe' and each_component['name'] == 'PE1':
        env_data['PE1_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'pe' and each_component['name'] == 'PE2':
        env_data['PE2_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'versadirector' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaDirector':
        env_data['VD_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'jump' and each_component['name'] == 'Jump':
        jump_ips = json.loads(each_component['ip_addr'])

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'versaanalytics' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics1':
        analytics_1 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'versaanalytics' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics2':
        analytics_2 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'versaanalytics' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics3':
        analytics_3 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

    elif each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper() and each_component['component_type'] == 'versaanalytics' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics4':
        analytics_4 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
```

I am trying to generate a **env_data** dictionary and the variables **analytics_X**.
Now the reason for this request is because this piece of code when run through a code quality tool gives critical warnings and needs to be further simplified for the code quality check to pass.
Anyone with any ideas? Help here

Comment: Your naming indicates a deeper problem in your data structure. You should make more use of functions, dictionaries and lists.

Comment: Without knowing how you intend to use the generated data, it is hard to give meaningful advices.

Answer (score 0):

You repeat a lot of checks. Don't do that. To simplify, just nest unique `if`s under a repeated `if` statement:

```
for each_component in component_objects:
    if each_component['region_type'] == deploy_json['env_type'].upper():

        if each_component['component_type'] == 'pe':
            if each_component['name'] == 'PE1':
                env_data['PE1_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
            elif each_component['name'] == 'PE2':
                env_data['PE2_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

        elif each_component['component_type'] == 'versadirector' and each_component['name'] == 'VersaDirector':
            env_data['VD_HOSTNAME'] = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]

        elif each_component['component_type'] == 'jump' and each_component['name'] == 'Jump':
            jump_ips = json.loads(each_component['ip_addr'])

        elif each_component['component_type'] == 'versaanalytics':
            if each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics1':
                analytics_1 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
            elif each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics2':
                analytics_2 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
            elif each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics3':
                analytics_3 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
            elif each_component['name'] == 'VersaAnalytics4':
                analytics_4 = each_component['hostname'].split('.')[0]
```

This is almost as simplified as it can get. You should use functions if you want to simplify further, because at the moment, there are a lot of repeating tasks. Anything that gets repeated can be replaced by a function.